# Blank rows/ spaces when copying and pasting from Excel to Keynote Chart

Tags: ms-office, keynote

When I copy from Excel for Mac (version 16.11), and paste into Keynote (version 7.3.1), the formatting jumps every time. This means I have to paste individual cells one by one instead of the whole table of numbers, which is time consuming every time.

Eg 1:

Copy(CMD+C) this from Excel:
[image]

Paste (CMD+V) and get this in Keynote:
[image: Screen Shot 2018-03-19 at 1.58.53 PM.png]

Eg 2:

Copy(CMD+C) this:

[image]

Get(CMD+V) this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/322399/edit) your question to detail the actual steps you're taking when copying and pasting? I'm trying to replicate the problem at my end.

Comment: Have you attempted to move the data from Excel to Apple Numbers first before sending them to Keynote?

Comment: @Monomeeth, it's just a simple CMD+C, CMD+V copy and paste from Excel. It never used to happen in the past, but it started happening about a few weeks ago for me (I can't really recall if there was any updates prior to this starting).

Comment: @drivec, when I move the data to Numbers, it works perfectly. But I'm trying to find a solution from Excel to Keynote, as it will be additional steps to paste into Numbers and then to Keynote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple workaround: just copy paste into Apple's Notes, then paste it into Keynote. Fast and easy.